# Mercurial project hosting

Tags: web-applications, mercurial, dvcs, project-hosting

I need a project hosting with:

- mercurial support;
- lightweight, but usable issue tracker (github`s one is pretty close);
- both public and private repositories/trackers/wiki and so on support;
- cool customizable dashboard;
- API and hooks (optional, but nice to have).

I've found [codebasehq](http://codebasehq.com) which looks promising, but It doesn't allow to publish anything, but commit history.

Some points:

- I'm fine with paying for good project hosting;
- bitbucket is not an option (huge list of reasons is omitted);
- usability and reliability is the most important things for me.

Thanks in advance.

**UPD1: Primary reasons I want move from bitbucket:**

- totally unusable issue tracker: it makes me cry every time I use one;
- lack of [list of my assigned tickets for all projects](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4580/list-of-my-issues), suggested solution seems early alpha (have accessibility problems and lack basic features);
- not well-designed notification system (sends me notifications about mine comments and so on)
- dashboard sucks;
- slow and "wonfixish" reaction (IMHO) on feature requests and bug reports.

**UPD2:**

Assembla is more appropriate project hosing then fogbugz + klin according my criteria
list, so I'm granting bounty to @lazybadger`s answer, but not accepting it, because Assembla works very bad with mercurial repositories and doesn't care about users.

Thanks for your suggestions, guys!

Comment: Bitbucket supports all the things you are looking for so your reasons for not using it seem pretty relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [FogBugz](https://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) + [Kiln](https://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/).

The issue tracker is just priceless. Wiki, AP, hooks, plugins, everything's there.

Our company switched project hosting + managing/issues tracking to FogBugz/Kiln last year, and we're totally satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for nice suggestion, @bigyellowcactus. Looks promissing, but not really lightweight.
I'll share my experience with FogCreek tools in couple days.

Comment: It less usable for me than bitbucket. I tried to get used to it, but It still looks and feels complicated.

Answer (score 1):

[Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/) - separate [spaces](https://www.assembla.com/workspaces) or [Assembla Portfolio](http://portfolio.assembla.com/)

I have to mention:

- Issue-tracker is good, maybe not so lightweight, but not heavyweight
- Mercurial supported, but it's a "a poor cousin" [since recently](http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/88300/Spring-Cleaning-at-Assembla.aspx) -
  no basic functionality lost, but default hg repo-broswer in iframe is
  just ugly, compared to Git or SVN custom repo-browser
- Private and public **spaces with custom tools** exist
- Dashboard as separate tool is deprecated (see [Assembla Blog](http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/88300/Spring-Cleaning-at-Assembla.aspx) again: "Stopping Development/Support
  Maintaining Current Installations, No New Installations"), but [Space Stream-tab](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/customlocations-greylink/stream) is good candidate
- [REST API](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/breakoutdocs/wiki/Assembla_REST_API) and [Webhooks tool](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/breakoutdocs/wiki/Webhook_message_templates)

Comment: Thanks, @lazy-badger!
Awesome! Not perfect, but better than other project hosting platforms I used.  
"Spring cleaning" is awful thing. Really sucking unmaintained mercurial support is HUGE downside. Negative feedback from users about the change is another huge downside.  
It could be *almost perfect* project hosting, but they don't care about the users, which is the worst downside for any project.

Answer (score 1):

I have to recommend Kiln & Fogbugz too. Superb tools and flexible pricing for teams of all sizes.

Here's a Youtube video link of Fogcreek co-founder Joel Spolsky talking about what these tools can do for you.

http://youtu.be/r5HNI9aMzOE